# Why spring-webflux application is running on tomcat as default, instead of netty?

Tags: spring-webflux

I created a Spring-webflux project using below `pom.xml` but when I am starting the application, it's starting on Tomcat. Shouldn't it start default on Netty?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>reactive-rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>reactive-rest</name>

    <properties>
        <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-messaging</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java-version}</source>
                        <target>${java-version}</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

</project>
```

The main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, WebMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class ReactiveRestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReactiveRestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Start logs:

```
2020-11-09 18:29:26.311  INFO 80838 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2020-11-09 18:29:26.375  INFO 80838 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-11-09 18:29:26.390  INFO 80838 --- [  restartedMain] c.o.r.ReactiveRestApplication            : Started ReactiveRestApplication in 18.256 seconds (JVM running for 25.2)
```

I even tried removing tomcat dependency but still the application starts on Tomcat

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Even tried setting `spring.main.web-application-type: reactive` but still tomcat.

Update: I kept only `spring-boot-starter-webflux` and removed every other dependency. This time also service started on 'Tomcat'

Answer (score 1):

If you look up the different libraries you have included on mvnrepository you can see that [spring-boot-starter-websocket](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-websocket/2.3.5.RELEASE)

Has a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-web` which in turn will force default start your app as a springMVC application, and not a webflux application.

My assumption is that websockets are already included in the webflux dependency.

Comment: I commented out every other dependency. Kept only `spring-boot-starter-webflux`, but still service started on Tomcat.

Comment: then you need to post your mvn dependency tree

Comment: I created a fresh project with only webflux as dependency and that started on Netty. That mean you are right, something exist into my dependencies. Adding them one by one. Let's see what's causing the issue

Comment: As i said before, if you post your dependency tree we can probably figure it out

Comment: Had to exclude `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` from `spring-boot-starter-webflux`
After removing/excluding web and tomcat dependencies, the maven was not upgrading the dependencies, as the tomcat was still into dependency tree. So I needed to refresh/reload the maven project. Then it started on Netty.

Comment: > My assumption is that websockets are already included in the webflux dependency: No

Comment: @TheCoder please provide any documentation to back up your claim. the `ReactiveWebsockHandler` is provided in the reactive package https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/socket/WebSocketHandler.html so afaik your claim is wrong.

Comment: I found that importing spring-boot-starter-hateoas will also cause the switchover to tomcat.

Comment: `I commented out every other dependency. Kept only spring-boot-starter-webflux, but still service started on Tomcat.` you wrote this, which was then not true also there is no hatoas dependency posted in any of the information above. If you had posted the output from mvn dependency:tree we could have solved this in 5 minutes.