# Spring boot, test which webserver is used under-the-hood

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, netty

I createad a new Spring boot 3 reactive app, using webflux and Netty webserver.

In my previous experiences with this reactive stack, it happened many times that the webserver switched automatically from Netty to Tomcat by mistake without even noticing (e.g. adding `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in the classpath) that automatically makes the application blocking instead of reactive.

I'd like to make sure that the webserver is (and will always be) Netty via integration test. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: As long as you don't have `spring-boot-starter-web` it will use the same, else it will indeed prefer Tomcat. You can always set `spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE` to your `application.properties`.

Comment: sure, but devs can always add that dependecy without knowing the conseguences, so I'd prefer to have something "error-proof" that force  the reactive stack and the usage of netty.

Comment: I tried to set `spring.main.web-application-type=REACTIVE` but if I add the `spring-boot-starter-web ` dependencies, the app runs on Tomcat anyway

Comment: see here for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64752204/why-spring-webflux-application-is-running-on-tomcat-as-default-instead-of-netty

the webserver switched to Tomcat without even adding `spring-boot-starter-web` directly but just because `spring-boot-starter-websocket` depends on it.

I'd like to avoid exactly these unintentional behaviours

Comment: Do you want to check it from outside (probably with a http request), or by some test in project/application itself?

Comment: How did you set `spring.main.web-application-type`? If you put this in you `application.properties` and there is one in test as well this won't work as the one from test will override this. You can set the type on the `SpringApplication` as well in your `main` method, however that is ignored in the test as well. The only, sort of, fool proof way would be to add an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` which sets this and make sure that it is always applied. Or write some checkstyle rule which checks for conflicting dependencies.